# Show that $f$ is continuous at 0.

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

EDIT: Fixed the limit.

This is a question from Spivak's Calculus, Ch.6, ex. 3.

> Suppose that $f$ is a function satisfying $$|f(x)|\leq |x| \forall x$$
>   Show that $f$ is continuous at 0. (Notice that f(0) must equal 0.

I do not understand the solution at all. Could someone please explain it to me?

Solution: $\lim_{h\to 0} f(h) = 0, $since$ |h|\lt\delta $implies that$ |f(h) - f(0)| = |f(h)\lt \delta$

Where does the $h$ come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to show that $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=f(0)$. Now $\lim_{x\to 0}|f(x)|\le \lim_{x\to 0} |x|=0$, hence $\lim_{x\to 0}|f(x)|=0$, hence $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=f(0)$.

Or in other words, the definition of continuity at $x_0$ is that for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta$ such that $|x-x_0|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$. In this case $x_0=0$, and $f(x_0)=f(0)=0$, hence this just reduces to showing $|x|<\delta\implies |f(x)|<\epsilon$, so since $|f(x)\le|x|$, just take $\delta=\epsilon$ (since $|x|<\epsilon\implies |f(x)|<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

If you have *noticed* $f(0) = 0$, then also notice that $|f(h) - f(0)| = |f(h)|$.

By the property of $f$, $|f(h)| < |h|$ and $h$ is chosen such that $|h| < \delta$.

Therefore $f(h) < \delta$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [squeeze theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) in calculus.

Here, $0 \leq f(x) \leq |x|$, at $x=0$ ,$f(x)=0$.

Hence the graph squeezes between $y=0$ & $y=|x|$

or at $x=0$, $f(x)$ limits to $0$.